# How to Set Selection start Date grater than Today date in Telerik raddatepiker

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am try to set Selection start date in telerik RadDatePicker in design Side by using RangeSelectionEndDate propriety.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="datEffectiveDate" runat="server" Enabled="false"  Width="200px">
                        <Calendar ID="calEffectiveDate" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true" RangeSelectionStartDate=<%# Eval(DateTime.Now, 'mm/dd/yyyy' %> >
                        </Calendar>
                    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Please help how to set Seletion start date should be greater than equal to today date in telerik raddatepiker on html side.

Comment: I think nobody knows that how to do this, shem on guys

Comment: any one to want prove your self

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code .

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="datEffectiveDate" runat="server" Enabled="true" Width="200px"
MinDate="<%# DateTime.Today.Date %>">
```

When using a databinding expression such as <%# DateTime.Today.Date %>, then you have to call Page.DataBind() (or ltrDate.DataBind() if that's the only databound control) from your code-behind (e.g. in Page_Load).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this helped.